# CSS drop down menu does not overlap

Tags: html, css, menu, z-index

I have a problem with a css dropdown menu. I will post the code if any of you want, if the dropdown opens, a element under the menu will go down and won't get over it. Please help I can't figure it out! And so far I know, i tried z-index and it does nothing. ( Sorry for my bad english. )

Comment: make fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ Before i see code, from what you have described: dropdown should be absolutely positioned...

Comment: apply the z-index property to the parent first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would try something like this:

```
<ul>

    <li>
       ItemA
       <div class="popup-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>sub menu item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

.popup-menu {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden; /*Should make it auto size */
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Swimbi app](http://f-source.com/) to generate clean CSS of drop down menu.
Good looking menu designs available for free.